# Flexbox set with 0 gap and margin still has a small gap between rows

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use a flexbox to show a few 600x300 images and for some reason, I'm getting a small gap between the rows even though I'm specifying a 0 gap and margin. Screenshot: https://imgur.com/QsKRzXB

```
.gallery {
  display: flex;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  gap:0px;
  margin:0px;  
}
```

My HTML to fill the flexbox is a loop going through a list of directory names; it will pull a cover.jpg from the directories and embed a clickable hyperlink to the directory with that image. I'm not doing anything with vWrap in the CSS, but I've tried explicitly adding a 0 margin and padding as well.

```
<body>

<!-- (B) VIDEO GALLERY -->
<div class="gallery"><?php
  // (B1) GET VIDEO FOLDERS
      
  $vid = glob(__DIR__ . '\*' , GLOB_ONLYDIR);
  
  usort($vid, function ($file1, $file2) {});
  
// (B2) OUTPUT FOLDERS
if (count($vid) > 0)
    { 
        foreach ($vid as $v)
        {

            $file = str_replace("'","&#39;",basename($v));
            //Can exclude certain directories this way
            if (str_contains($file,'Era') or str_contains($file,'VideoGallery') or str_contains($file,'Streaming')) {}
            else
                {
                    printf("<div class='vWrap'>
                    <a href='$file'><img src='$file\cover.jpg' width='600' height='300'></a>
                    </div>");
    }
        }
                }
?></div>

</body>
```

Comment: Post the rendered HTML, not the PHP

Answer (score -1):

Got it, I explicitly added `width:600px` and `height:300px` for `vWrap` in the CSS. I find it weird I had to do that since I set the height and width in the href (if anyone has something to add, please do). Edit: I understand now that the href size is specific to the image itself and not the flex container/div.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted, but you need to update your question with HTML so this page has value to the community. It's not all about you. :)